# RTK Query problem: I can see the fetched data in Redux devtools but there no data in hook

Tags: reactjs, toolkit, rtk-query

I've just started to learn RTK Query and I can't display a component that depends on fetching data(Albums.js). The task is: to display the list of users and buttons, when clicking the button 'albums' I need to display modal with the list of albums having the same id as the clicked user. So, when clicking I can see the albums in Redux Toolkit and in Network calls but  there is no data in useGetAlbumsQuery() in the component Albums.js. What is wrong?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzLR1.png)
*usersApi.js*

```
import {createApi, fetchBaseQuery} from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'

export const usersApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'usersApi',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({baseUrl: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/'}),
    tagTypes: ['Users', 'Albums'],
    endpoints: (build) => ({
        getUsers: build.query({
            query: () => `users`,
            providesTags: ['Users'],
        }),
        getAlbums: build.query({
            query: (userId = '') => `albums?userId=${userId}`,
            providesTags: ['Albums'] 
        }),
        transformResponse: response => ({
           response
        }),
        updateAlbums: build.mutation({
            query: (body) => ({
                url: 'albums',
                method: 'GET',
                body,
            }),
            invalidatesTags: [{type: 'Albums'}]
        })

    })
})

export const {useGetUsersQuery, useGetAlbumsQuery} = usersApi
```

*Users.js*

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { useGetAlbumsQuery, useGetUsersQuery } from './redux'
import Albums from './Albums'

const User = () => {
    const {data: users, isLoading, isError} = useGetUsersQuery()
    const [userId, setUserId] = useState()
    useGetAlbumsQuery(userId)

    return (
        <>
            {isLoading && <h1>Loading...</h1>}
            {isError && <h1>Something has gone wrong</h1>}
                <ul>
                    {
                        users?.map(el => (
                            <li key={el.id}>
                                <p>{el.name}</p> 
                                <div>
                                    <button onClick={(e)=> setUserId(e.target.id)} id={el.id}>Albums</button>
                                    <button>Posts</button>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        ))  
                    }
                </ul>
                <Albums />
        </>
    )
}
export default User
```

*Albums.js*

```
import {useGetAlbumsQuery, useGetUsersQuery} from './redux'

const Albums = () => {
    const {data} = useGetAlbumsQuery()
 
    return (
        <>
            <h3>hello</h3>
                {data?.map(el => {
                 <p key={el.id}>{el.title}</p>
             })}
        </>
    ) 
}
export default Albums
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your API call [https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums?userId=""](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums?userId=%22%22)  returns an empty array that is why no data is displayed on Album component , try passing userid as query param to your useGetAlbumsQuery(userId) like this.

You also need to pass the selected userId to your Album.js after pressing album button.

your Users.js may look like

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { useGetAlbumsQuery, useGetUsersQuery } from './redux'
import Albums from './Albums'

const User = () => {
    const {data: users, isLoading, isError} = useGetUsersQuery()
    const [userId, setUserId] = useState()
    useGetAlbumsQuery(userId)

    return (
        <>
            {isLoading && <h1>Loading...</h1>}
            {isError && <h1>Something has gone wrong</h1>}
                <ul>
                    {
                        users?.map(el => (
                            <li key={el.id}>
                                <p>{el.name}</p> 
                                <div>
                                    <button onClick={(e)=> setUserId(e.target.id)} id={el.id}>Albums</button>
                                    <button>Posts</button>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        ))  
                    }
                </ul>
                <Albums userId={userId} />
        </>
    )
}
export default User
```

and your Album.js is

```
import {useGetAlbumsQuery, useGetUsersQuery} from './redux'

const Albums = ({userId}) => {
    const {data, isSuccess} = useGetAlbumsQuery(userId)
 
    return (
        <>
            <h3>hello</h3>
                {isSuccess && data?.map(el => {
                 <p key={el.id}>{el.title}</p>
             })}
        </>
    ) 
}
export default Albums
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: No, it still doesn't work( Besides, API call returns the needed array, I can see it in Redux devtools and in console Network. It all works and I have no idea why I can't see the data at the screen.

Comment: I've changed my code the way you said and added 'return'  for iteration in Album.js and all works! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`useGetAlbumsQuery(userId)` and `useGetAlbumsQuery()` make two different requests to the server and return different data.

The first might be `albums?userId=12` and the seconds will be to `albums?userId=undefined`.

So as @sa-jid already said, you will have to pass down that `userId` to your `Albums` component.